# Looking for other sources for rubygem

Tags: rubygems

I have been having issues getting gems from rubyforge on windows.The computer just hangs.Are there any other sources which I can use.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

GitHub(www.github.com) has a large collection of rubygems.